# A Question about an example in Durrett's Probability textbook

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading an example in Durrett's book: [Probability : Theory and Example, 4th edition](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) (pdf verison) (Example 3.4.7, p.112)

The scenario is as follows:

> Define $Y_1,Y_2...$ be independent random variables with $P(Y_m=1) = 1/m$ and $P(Y_m=0) = 1 - 1/m$, and then we can compute the mean and variance as
>   $$EY_m=1/m; \;\; var(Y_m)=1/m-1/m^2$$
>   and the author also mentioned that $var(S_n) \sim \log(n)$;

Here are my questions:

1. I'm not very clear about the notation "$\sim$" above, what does this notation means?? and why $var(S_n) \sim \log(n)$
2. I also wonder why $var(Y_m) = 1/m - 1/m^2$? I mean
   $$var(Y_m) = E(Y_m^2) - (E(Y_m))^2 = E(Y_m^2) - 1/m^2 $$
   but how to make $E(Y_m^2)= 1/m?$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the notation is: $a_n \sim b_n \iff \frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 1$. Here, using comparison with an integral you get that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \sim \log n$$
2. $$\begin{align}\text{var } Y_m &= EY_m^2 - (EY_m)^2
    \\&= (1/m\times 1^2 + (1-1/m)\times 0^2) - (1/m\times 1 + (1-1/m)\times 0)^2 \\&= 1/m - 1/m^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for reply; @mookid ; For question 2, can I think this way: $E(Y_m^2)=1\cdot P(Y_m^2 =1) + 0 \cdot P(Y_m^2=0) = P(Y_m^2=1)$ and since $P(Y_m =1) = P(Y_m^2 = 1) = 1/m$ so we get $E(Y_m^2)=1\cdot P(Y_m^2 =1) = 1/m?$

Comment: this is correct!